# "stack level too deep" when generating cousin class of existing class

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, stack-overflow

I am writing a ruby module for constraint processing.

(as my little experience, mainly it's about instancialize Variables using given Domains and search&prune)

## My intention

Instances of `Constraint` are to be initialized with a set of variable names, and a block. The block will be evaluated to check whether an initialization satisfies the constraint.

Fed with a block, its class method `Constraint.subclass` returns a subclass of `Constraint`, say `Subclass1`

In `Subclass1`, there is be a initializer with pre-defined block (the one fed to `Constraint.subclass`), and a class method `Subclass1.invert`. The latter returns another subclass of `Constraint` , say `Subclass2`, by using `Constraint.subclass` again.

And the pre-defined block in `Subclass2` should be inverted version of the one in `Subclass1`

## Current situation

The code more or less did as I intended. `Constraint.subclass` works, but it seems `Subclass.invert` works only if the pre-defined block are of determined arity. Else `stack level too deep` will occur.

```
#worked
EQ = Constraint.subclass {|a,b| a == b }
NE = EQ.invert
ALL_DISTINCT = Constraint.subclass {|*args| args.uniq.size == args.size}

#raised stackoverflow
HAVE_DUPLICATE = ALL_DISTINCT.invert
```

## Source

in ruby1.9 are listed below. Less corelative methods are omitted, and a full version is available at https://gist.github.com/2882291

```
module Solver
  class Constraint # class method for a subclass
    def self.subclass &block
      Class.new(self) do
        @@block = block
        def initialize *args
          super *args, &@@block
        end

        def self.invert # class method for a cousin class of current subclass
          p "#{self}.invert"
          new_block = proc {|*args| not @@block.call(*args)}
          self.superclass.subclass &new_block
        end
      end
    end

    def initialize *vars, &block
      # block will be substituted with variable in vars
      raise ArgumentError "array of variable names is required"unless vars.is_a? Array
      raise ArgumentError "block is expected" unless block_given?
      @vars = vars.freeze
      @proc = block.freeze
    end

    # less related methods
  end

  # predefined constraint schema
  EQ = Constraint.subclass {|a,b| a == b }
  NE = EQ.invert

  GT = Constraint.subclass {|a,b| a > b }
  NGT = GT.invert

  LT = Constraint.subclass {|a,b| a < b }
  NLT = LT.invert

  ALL_DISTINCT = Constraint.subclass {|*args| args.uniq.size == args.size}
  #HAVE_DUPLICATE = ALL_DISTINCT.invert
end
```

Comment: Do you have unit tests that show what currently works?

Comment: @OscarDelBen Thanks for the reminder. To my surprise, `Constraint` and all of its subclass shared the same class-variable @@block.